# NullPointerException when accessing overriden val in abstract constructor

Tags: scala

Consider the following (simplified) example:

```
abstract class Bar[T] {
    val f: PartialFunction[T, T]
    val default: PartialFunction[T, T] = { case x => x }
    val chained = f orElse default
}

class Foo extends Bar[Int] {
    val f: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = { case 1 => 2 }
}
```

And watch it crash:

```
scala> val foo = new Foo
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Bar.<init>(<console>:8)
        at Foo.<init>(<console>:6)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
        at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
        ....
```

However, if we put `chained` in the concrete class:

```
abstract class Bar[T] {
    val f: PartialFunction[T, T]
    val default: PartialFunction[T, T] = { case x => x }
}

class Foo extends Bar[Int] {
    val f: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = { case 1 => 2 }
    val chained = f orElse default
}
```

It works as expected:

```
scala> val foo = new Foo
foo: Foo = Foo@16132c4
```

I have to admit I have absolutely no idea what is happening here. Bug? (This is on Scala 2.8.1.)

Comment: See this question for a solution/workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Why is my abstract or overriden val null?" https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki/Initialization-Order

Comment: A: Link is now 404, B: some people want to avoid lazy vals

Comment: Link is now [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html) and it's poor practice to answer with links.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: This is an optimization done at compile time. The compiler recognizes that you override `f` in `Bar`. Therefore, the "constructor" of `Bar` executes first the stuff from `Foo` -- sans `f`! -- and *then* the stuff in the definition of `Bar`. Therefore, `f` is not defined when `chained` is constructed.

I call bug.