# Question on the initialization of abstract type class in scala

Tags: scala, types, abstract

I define a class with abstract type as follow:

```
abstract class AbsCell2{
    type T
    val init: T
    private var value: T = {
         println("Hello "+init);
         init
    }
    def get : T = value
    def set(x : T) = { value = x}
}
```

Now I instantiate an object with type Int

```
scala> val cell = new AbsCell2{type T = Int ; val init = 10}
Hello 0
cell: AbsCell2{type T = Int} = $anon$1@969ebb
```

Pay attention to the output from `println`. It seams the variable `init` hasn't been initialized as 10.  Note that the version of scala is 2.9.0-1

Comment: This example is borrowed from the presentation provided by Martin Ordersky. http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/

Comment: But now execute `cell.init` in the REPL and it _will_ show you 10.  Is your question about why it doesn't print 10 before the object is initialized?

Comment: I think 爱国者 is also asking why `cell.get` returns 0, and how to get it to return 10.

Comment: But when you call cell.get after the object is created , it split out 0. If you call cell.set(20), then cell.get, it print out 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for Scala's [early initializers](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/nielsen/Tue,%202009-06-02,%2013:16/early-defs.pdf),

```
scala> val cell = new {type T = Int ; val init = 10} with AbsCell2
Hello 10
cell: AbsCell2{val init: Int; type T = Int} = $anon$1@1efa9557

scala> cell.get
res0: cell.T = 10
```

Early initializers allow you to allocate a new object and set some specific fields *before* the class constructor runs. In this case, since `value` depends on `init`, we use the early initializer syntax (`new { val init = ... } with AbsCell2`) to first set `init` so that the class constructor can properly initialize `value`.

See also this question: [In Scala, what is an "early initializer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer)

Comment: Excuse me, What is "early initializer" syntax about ?

Comment: Excuse me , What is the different between new {type T = Int ; val init = 10} with AbsCell2 and new AbsCell2{type T = Int ; val init = 10}

Answer (score 0):

Change from val to def:

```
abstract class AbsCell2{
  type T
  def init: T
  private var value: T = {
     println("Hello "+init);
     init
  }
  def get : T = value
  def set(x : T) = { value = x}
}
```

It works as expected:

```
scala> val cell = new AbsCell2{type T = Int ; def init = 10}
Hello 10
cell: AbsCell2{type T = Int} = $anon$1@4302df5
```

Answer (score 0):

For question about difference between `new { type T = Int ; val init = 10 }` with AbsCell2 and `new AbsCell2 { type T = Int ; val init = 10 }`。

The first one is the so-called early-initializers or pre-initialized fields(mentioned in Abstract Members chapter in Programming In Scala)。It allows the subclass to initialize fields before the super class is called。
In this case, init has already been set as 10 before the initialization of AbsCell2。

The latter one is normal inheritance, it creates an anonymous class then extends AbsCell2, just like:

```
 class AbsCell' extends AbsCell {
    type T = Int 
    val init = 10 
 }
```

However, the anonymous class gets initialized after the abstract class AbsCell2, so init are not available in the initialization of itself, namely, init is the default value of the Type, 0 in this case. Therefore, you get 0 in the print。

use `scalac -Xprint:all Test.scala`, you will see the following:

```
 abstract class AbsCell2 extends Object {
    <stable> <accessor> def init(): Object;
    ....
   def <init>(): AbsCell2 = {
    AbsCell2.super.<init>();
    AbsCell2.this.value = {
      scala.this.Predef.println("Hello ".+(AbsCell2.this.init()));
      AbsCell2.this.init()
    };
    ()
   }
 };

 // normal initialization
 final class anon$1 extends AbsCell2 {
    private[this] val init: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def init(): Int = anon$1.this.init;
    ....
    def <init>(): <$anon: AbsCell2> = {
     anon$1.super.<init>();
     anon$1.this.init = 10;
     ()
   }
 };

 // early initialization
 final class anon$2 extends AbsCell2 {
   private[this] val init: Int = _;
   <stable> <accessor> def init(): Int = anon$2.this.init;
   ....
   def <init>(): <$anon: AbsCell2> = {
     val init: Int = 10;
     anon$2.this.init = init;
     anon$2.super.<init>();
     ()
   }
 }
```

From the code, we can see that for normal initialization, init is set to 3 after the initialization of super class AbsCell2, when AbsCell2.this.init() gets invoked, it actually refers to the subclass' init field and 3 is yet to set, so we get the default type value。On the contrary, early initialization first set init to 3 then call super class initialization。