# What is the purpose of extending an anonymous type in Scala?

Tags: scala, anonymous-types, extending

I'm trying to get a better understanding of Scala, and I can't seem to find a valid usecase for code like the following:

```
class C extends { def m() { /* ... */ } }
```

What is the rationale for allowing such constructs?

Thanks!

Comment: The example you give isn't a structural type, but an anonymous class. Not that it explains why you can extend it...

Comment: Right you are, I updated the title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess the only rationale here is "avoid special cases if possible". You can extend any class, an anonymous class is a class, so you can extend an anonymous class.

Comment: You are probably right (+1). Would love an actual use case, though, if one does indeed exist :)

Comment: I agree with Kim, inheriting allows to share behaviors or to represent a given hierarchy. But If the parent class in anonymous, you cannot have two child classes extending the same parent class.

Comment: You can't extend `final` classes. I suppose anonymous classes could be made final, but in the absence of any reason to extend an anonymous class it probably doesn't make any difference whether they're final or not.

Comment: I'd like to remind users that this answer is wrong. It has been the accepted answer for a few years now and it's misleading since it has nothing to do with avoiding special cases. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

That is not, in fact, an anonymous class! It's an early initializer and it runs as part of the constructor that goes before its superclass.
Quoting the excellent answer from [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer):

```
abstract class X {
    val name: String
    val size = name.size
}

class Y extends {
    val name = "class Y"
} with X
```

If the code were written instead as

```
class Z extends X {
    val name = "class Z"
}
```

then a null pointer exception would occur when Z got initialized, because size is initialized before name in the normal ordering of initialization (superclass before class).

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Early definitions](https://github.com/scala/scala.github.com/blob/master/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.md) and they deal with super class initialization order problem.