# Abstract fields in traits (Scala) - construction order

Tags: scala, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, traits

So I'm reading the [*Scala for the Impatient*](http://horstmann.com/scala/) book and one of the examples it uses is a `Logger` trait that essentially prints a `String` to some stream. In the example, it has a trait `ConsoleLogger` (which extends `Logger`) that prints the message out to `stdout` and `ShortLogger` (also extends `Logger`) that simply truncates the string if the length is too long. To change the maximum length of `ShortLogger` the book proposes uses an anonymous subclass, something like:

```
val acct = new SavingsAccount with ConsoleLogger with ShortLogger {
  val maxLength = 20
}
```

Where `ShortLogger` is a trait with an abstract `maxLength: Int` field and `SavingsAccount` is defined as

```
class SavingsAccount extends Account with Logged { ... }
```

Which makes sense to me (kind of). I'm assuming the construction order is:

1. `Logger` gets constructed first (since it is a super-trait of `ConsoleLogger`),
2. `ConsoleLogger`
3. `ShortLogger`
4. `Account`
5. `SavingsAccount`.
6. Then we have the anonymous subclass construction where we define the abstract `maxLength = 20`.

However, later on in the book, it gives a new `Logger` sub-trait:

```
trait FileLogger extends Logger {
  val filename: String
  val out = new PrintStream(filename)
  def log(msg: String) { out.println(msg); out.flush() }
}

val acct = new SavingsAccont with FileLogger {
  val filename = "myapp.log" // Does not work
}
```

It says it does not work due to the construction order. They propose the modification:

```
val acct = new {
  val filename: "myapp.log"
} with SavingsAccount with FileLogger
```

However, this definition seems to be similar to the one above with `maxLength`, so what am I missing between the above example and the bottom example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your construction order is entirely wrong. :-)

The first thing to be constructed is the class, then you go through the traits from left to right. It's a bit more complex to that -- there's linearization rules that deal with traits inherited multiple times, but that's about it.

So:

1. Account
2. Logged
3. SavingsAccount
4. ConsoleLogger
5. ShortLogger
6. Anonymous subclass

Now, to your question:

```
val acct = new SavingsAccont with FileLogger {
  val filename = "myapp.log" // Does not work
}

val acct = new {
  val filename: "myapp.log"
} with SavingsAccount with FileLogger
```

Note that the block of code comes first in the second example. That's known as [*early initialization*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer), and what it does is to apply that initialization before anything else.

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong with the construction order. However, I still have a question.. why does the first example where we override `maxLength` work but not when we do it in the second example with `filename` ? Why must the 2nd example have the early initialization?

Comment: @kstruct `FileLogger` goes before the anonymous function, and `val out` makes reference to `filename`, which has not been initialized yet, so it's value is `null`. See also the `-Xcheckinit` parameter of the compiler, which inserts code to detect, at run time, when an val is used before being initialized.