# Avoiding NPE in trait initialization without using lazy vals

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception

This is probably covered by the [blog entry](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.at/2010/03/nullpointer-when-mixed-traits-warning.html) by Jesse Eichar—still I can't figure out how to correct the following **without resorting to lazy vals** so that the NPE is fixed:

Given

```
trait FooLike { def foo: String }
case class Foo(foo: String) extends FooLike

trait Sys {
  type D <: FooLike
  def bar: D
}

trait Confluent extends Sys {
  type D = Foo
}

trait Mixin extends Sys {
  val global = bar.foo
}
```

First attempt:

```
class System1 extends Mixin with Confluent {
  val bar = Foo("npe")
}

new System1  // boom!!
```

Second attempt, changing mixin order

```
class System2 extends Confluent with Mixin {
  val bar = Foo("npe")
}

new System2  // boom!!
```

Now I use both `bar` and `global` very heavily, and therefore I don't want to pay a lazy-val tax just because Scala (2.9.2) doesn't get the initialisation right. What to do?

Comment: Actually, it was possible in my concrete case, to add `bar` as constructor argument: `class System3( val bar: Foo ) extends Confluent with Mixin; new System3( Foo( ":-)" ))`—but I'm still interested how to solve this if I hadn't had the possibility of the constructor arg.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an [early initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer):

```
class System1 extends {
  val bar = Foo("npe")
} with Mixin with Confluent {
  // ...
}

scala> new System1
res3: System1 = System1@1d0bfedd
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe after >4 years of Scala I'm still encountering new things!