# Can you assign an inherited field from a constructor?

Tags: scala, traits

Given:

```
trait Foo {
  var foo: Int
}

abstract class Bar(foo: Int) extends Foo

trait Baz {
  self: Bar =>
  foo = 4
}
```

I get the following error:

```
value foo in class Bar cannot be accessed in Baz with Bar
  foo = 4
  ^
```

However, if I change Bar to the following:

```
abstract class Bar(_foo: Int) extends Foo {
  foo = _foo
}
```

It works fine. Is there no way to assign an inherited field from the constructor? It almost seems like it's shadowing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the inherited field. You just have a shadowing issue (as you suspected). The following works (`Foo` unchanged):

```
abstract class Bar(_foo: Int) extends Foo

trait Baz {
  self: Bar =>

  foo = 4
}
```

Note that `_foo: Int` in `Bar`'s constructor does not define the field `foo`. But we can do now:

```
val x = new Bar(1) with Baz {
  // need to define foo
  var foo: Int = _
}

x.foo
//> res0: Int = 4
```

You might want to have a look at [early initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer) for what you do.