# Initializing an anonymous class with a trait

Tags: class, scala, inheritance, initialization, traits

Can someone help me understand the following behavior?

Simply put: what is the difference between the following two cases where...

#### I define a simple class `c` + trait `t`

```
scala> class c {val x=true; val y=this.x} 
defined class c

scala> trait t {}
defined trait t
```

#### I can instantiate a new "c with t"

```
scala> new c with t
res32: c with t = $anon$1@604f1a67
```

#### But I can't instantiate a new "[anonymous class just like c] with t"

```
scala> new {val x=true; val y=this.x} with t
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : type
 required: ?{def x: ?}
<console>:9: error: value x is not a member of object $iw
              new {val x=true; val y=this.x} with t
```

What's the difference between these two cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've stumbled on "early definition" syntax ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer)).

Check out section 5.1.6 of the language specification:

> An early definition is type-checked and evaluated in the scope which
>   is in effect just before the template being defined, augmented by any
>   type parameters of the enclosing class and by any early definitions
>   preceding the one being defined. In particular, any reference to `this`
>   in the right-hand side of an early definition refers to the identity
>   of `this` just outside the template. **Consequently, it is impossible that
>   an early definition refers to the object being constructed by the
>   template, or refers to one of its fields and methods, except for any
>   other preceding early definition in the same section.**

In your case the problem is with `this.x`. If you replace it with just `x`, so you're referring to the "preceding early definition" as mentioned in the last sentence above (thanks, @som-snytt !), it compiles.

Of course, you probably didn't intend to write an early initializer, so just write it as per Kristian Domagala's answer.

Comment: You only have to get rid of the this, as the boldface says. `new {val x=true; val y=x} with t`

Answer (score 29):

Is this what you're after:

```
new t {val x=true; val y=this.x}
```

If you have another trait, `u {}`, you can write `new t with u {val x=true; val y=this.x}`