# Scala class extends {}

Tags: scala, types

By chance I came across weird compiling Scala syntax:

```scala
class Some extends {
  def hi = println("hi")
}
```

Guys:

- Is it an official Scala supported syntax?
- Does it mean simply extending the `Object`?
- Does it somehow relate to "duck typing"?
- Do you know interesting or tricky usages of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a strange quirk in Scala's syntax. An extraneous `extends` is allowed before beginning the body of the class. Here are the relevant parts from the [Scala Syntax Summary](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html):

```
ClassDef          ::=  id [TypeParamClause] {ConstrAnnotation} [AccessModifier] 
                       ClassParamClauses ClassTemplateOpt 
ClassTemplateOpt  ::=  ‘extends’ ClassTemplate | [[‘extends’] TemplateBody]
ClassTemplate     ::=  [EarlyDefs] ClassParents [TemplateBody]
```

`ClassTemplateOpt` is everything after the class's parameters, in this case everything from `extends` onwards. The usual use of `extends` is the first alternation of `ClassTemplateOpt`, with `extends` being followed either by a parent or an early initializer. However, an early initializer cannot contain a `def`, and there is no way to interpret the contents of the braces as a parent. It cannot be a structural type because `hi` has a concrete definition.

The second alternation allows the class parameters to be immediately followed by the class body, without using `extends`. However, an optional `extends` is allowed. The `extends` in OP's code is an example of this, and is exactly equivalent to the same code without the optional extends:

```
class Some {
  def hi = println("hi")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually just a syntactical accident (I think). Scala allows [early definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer) which look like

```
class Some extends {
  ...
} with ATrait
```

so the parser also accepts `class Some extends { ... }` which is equivalent to `class Some { ... }` [(source)](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/383.html).

Comment: It appears pre-initialized/early definitions don't permit functions to be declared though.  Doing the following won't compile:

trait ATrait; class Some extends { def hi = println("hi")} with ATrait

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is Scala's structural typing or more commonly known as duck typing.

```
object LoudDuck {
    def quack(): String = "QUACK"
}

object QuietDuck {
    def quack(): String = "quack"
}

object CowDuck {
    def quack(): String = "moo"
}

def quackMyDuck(duck: { def quack(): String }) {
    println(duck.quack())
}

scala>quackMyDuck(LoudDuck)
QUACK

scala>

scala>quackMyDuck(QuietDuck)
quack

scala>

scala>quackMyDuck(CowDuck)
moo
```

You can also declare your stuctural types with the "type" keyword.

```
type Duck = { def quack(): String }

def quackMyDuck(duck: Duck) {
    println(duck.quack())
}
```

Comment: The examples you give _are_ structural typing, but the one in question isn't.

Comment: Consider `type T = { def hi = println("hi") }` - it doesn't compile, because structural types can't have definitions.