# Direct inheritance of trait fails, but proxy works

Tags: scala

Why does adding a proxy trait work and direct inheritance fail?

[I've created a runnable project over on github](https://github.com/leftofnull/so-inheritance)

if you clone the repo and run `sbt console` followed by `com.stackoverflow.question.main.Question.main(Array.empty[String])`, you should end up with the output:

```
this-is-the-host-name
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at net.ceedubs.ficus.FicusConfig$class.as(FicusConfig.scala:9)
  at net.ceedubs.ficus.SimpleFicusConfig.as(FicusConfig.scala:16)
  at com.stackoverflow.question.AppConfig$class.conn(Config.scala:12)
  at com.stackoverflow.question.main.BadDatabaseService$.conn(package.scala:12)
  at com.stackoverflow.module.HostConnector$class.getHost(Database.scala:25)
  at com.stackoverflow.question.main.BadDatabaseService$.getHost(package.scala:12)
  at com.stackoverflow.module.DatabaseConnector$class.$init$(Database.scala:18)
  at com.stackoverflow.question.main.BadDatabaseService$.<init>(package.scala:12)
  at com.stackoverflow.question.main.BadDatabaseService$.<clinit>(package.scala)
  at com.stackoverflow.question.main.Question$.main(App.scala:8)
  ... 43 elided
```

the first line `this-is-the-host-name` is generated from the package object `DatabaseService` while the `NullPointerException` is generated by the `BadDatabaseService` package object. Both are identical except that the `DatabaseService` inherits from a proxy trait, while `BadDatabaseService` inherits directly from the trait. The relevant code is here for convenience and can also be seen in the github repo.

package.scala:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question

import com.stackoverflow.module._
import com.stackoverflow.question.AppConfig

package main {
  trait DataConfig extends ModuleConfig {
    def conn = AppConfig.conn
  }

  object DatabaseService extends TableFunctions with HostConnector with DataConfig   // This works with the proxy
  object BadDatabaseService extends TableFunctions with HostConnector with AppConfig // This fails with NullPointerException, it's the ConfigFactory.load that returns null
}
```

Config.scala:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question

import com.stackoverflow.module.{ ModuleConfig, ModuleConfiguration }
import com.typesafe.config.{ Config, ConfigFactory }
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._

object AppConfig extends AppConfig

trait AppConfig extends ModuleConfig {

  def config: Config = ConfigFactory.load()
  def conn = config.as[ModuleConfiguration]("stackoverflow.conn")

  val name = config.as[String]("stackoverflow.name")
}
```

Please help me understand why I can't inherit directly from `AppConfig` and why `ConfigFactory.load` returns null when `AppConfig` is inherited but not when it's co-object is called via proxy in inherited through that.

Comment: Not marking as a duplicate because the question is different, but the answers are the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248520/scala-class-using-mutable-var-update-in-overriding-method/33266720#33266720

Comment: Ha. http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html  "no vals in traits" is a thing.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov even if I change the def config to val config and override it with an early initializer, object BadDatabaseService extends {
    override val config = ConfigFactory.load
  } with TableFunctions with HostConnector with AppConfig, I get the same result.

Comment: I added branches for both of these suggestions and neither works, same error is received.  See https://github.com/leftofnull/so-inheritance/tree/early-init or https://github.com/leftofnull/so-inheritance/tree/no-vals

Comment: It looks like the val which is actually the problem is `implicit val moduleConfigReader`. Can you try applying the solutions to it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One additional solution that wasn't suitable for the linked question is to make `AppConfig.name` a `lazy val`.

Comment: that yields the same results, https://github.com/leftofnull/so-inheritance/tree/lazy-vals

Comment: okay, per your comment above, changing it to: implicit lazy val moduleConfigReader: ValueReader resolved it. Thank you! https://github.com/leftofnull/so-inheritance/tree/lazy-implicit