# Implements trait with an anonymous object in Scala

Tags: scala, traits

I have a trait definition:

```
trait T {
  def name: String
}
```

I can create an object like:

```
val o = new {
  val name: String = "anonymous"
} with T
```

But I cannot create the object in the following way:

```
val o = new {
  def name: String = "anonymous"
} with T
```

The compiler said **';' or newline expected** in line `} with T`. The only  different is I used `def` instead of `val` in the second implementation.

I know that method can be defined in an anonymous object, but why I cannot use in this way here?

Comment: See [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-912).

Comment: The compiler error I get is "error: only concrete field definitions allowed in early object initialization section"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curly brackets in your two examples are "early definitions", explained here:

[In Scala, what is an "early initializer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer)

So it's initialization code, and not something that gets mixed in to your object.

The idea was raised on the Scala JIRA, and closed as "not a bug", here:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-912