# A weird NullPointerException in scala

Tags: scala

the code goes here:

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]
  val height = contents.length
  val width = if(height ==0 ) 0 else contents(0).length

  override def toString = contents(0)
}
class ArrayElement(override val contents: Array[String]) extends Element

class LineElementT(s: String) extends Element {
  override def contents = Array(s)
}

class LineElementF(s: String) extends Element {
  override val contents = Array(s)
}
```

these three sub-classes are OK except the `LineElementF`, which throws an `NullPointerException` when creating instance with `val lef = new LineElementF("Wrong")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This NPE happens at height initialization. At the moment of height initialization val contents of LineElementF is not initialized.

You can avoid this NPE by declaring both height and width as lazy:

```
lazy val height = contents.length
lazy val width = if(height ==0 ) 0 else contents(0).length
```

Comment: thanks, but could you tell me why the other two sub-classes work well?

Comment: The difference is, that you defined `contents` once as `val` and once as `def. The right part of `val` is evaluated at construction, the one of `def`at call time. You can declare contents as `lazy val contents` to let it be evaluated only once when it is called the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The Scala language also has a special syntax (sometimes called [early definitions or early initilizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4712468/1804173)), which allows to execute the constructor of a subclass before the constructor of its superclass:

```
class LineElementEI(s: String) extends {
  override val contents = Array(s)
} with Element
```

To clarify why regular "late initialization" does not work with your `LineElementF`: In the body of the superclass you are trying to evaluate `contents.length`, but the body of the subclass is only evaluated *after* the superclass, so `contents` is still `null`. You can either solve it be using lazy evaluation on all fields which depend on subclass initialization or change the initialization order as shown above.