# Scala object extends nothing

Tags: scala, extend

I came across a piece of code in our codebase, which looked invalid to me, but compiled successfully and worked.

```scala
object Main extends {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    print("Hello World")
  }
}
```

> Hello World

Can someone explain me, what happens here?
Does `Main` class extend here an anonymous `class`/`trait`?

Comment: ugh why indeed does that abomination compile

Comment: this behaviour is dropped in dotty http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/early-initializers.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we decompile the code using `scala -Xprint:typer`, we see that `Main` extends `AnyRef`:

```
scalac -Xprint:typer Main.scala                                                                                               
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // Main.scala
package com.yuvalitzchakov {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): com.yuvalitzchakov.Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = scala.Predef.print("Hello World")
  }
}
```

This is also documented in the [Scala specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions) under object/class definition:

> An object definition defines a
>   single object of a new class. Its most general form is `object m
>   extends t`. Here, `m` is the name of the object to be defined, and `t` is a
>   template of the form
>
> `sc with mt1 with … with mtn { stats }` which defines the base classes,
>   behavior and initial state of m. **The extends clause `extends sc with
>   mt1 with … with mtn` can be omitted, in which case extends scala.AnyRef
>   is assumed.**

This syntax is also valid for [*early initializers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer):

```
abstract class X {
  val name: String
  val size = name.size
}

class Y extends {
  val name = "class Y"
} with X
```

Answer (score 2):

It desugars into

```
object Main extends Object
```

You can check this by compiling with `scalac -print`.

[Grammar](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/bf5fefa3fce5df83505fae2520f884f58d76e629/spec/13-syntax-summary.md) states

```
ClassTemplateOpt  ::=  ‘extends’ ClassTemplate | [[‘extends’] TemplateBody]
```

where

```
TemplateBody      ::=  [nl] ‘{’ [SelfType] TemplateStat {semi TemplateStat} ‘}’
```

so it does seem to be specified as valid if we examine `[[‘extends’] TemplateBody]`, as far as I understand.