# Scala late trait initialization

Tags: scala, initialization

Usually the "memeber" in trait is defined as `def variable:Type`, then other memebers which depend on `variable` uses `lazy val` to prevent `variable` being null when getting initialized.

However if it is a piece of logic, e.g. a function call depends on `variable` will still throw null exception. Like the code below:

```
  trait A {

    def variable:Seq[String]

    if (variable.size > 3) // check
      println("too many strings")

  }


  case class B(vs:String*) extends A {
    override val variable: Seq[String] = vs
    //override def hi(): Unit = ???
  }

  val b = B("x", "y", "z")
  println(b)
```

This will throw error "A.variable() is null".

Strangely, if I wrote variable as given constructor parameter, the error is gone.

```
  case class B(override val variable:String*) extends A {
    //override def hi(): Unit = ???
  }
```

How I can delay the "check" and why the second case doesn't throw exception?

Comment: I would advise either using an `abstract class` or move such checks to another factory-like trait.

Comment: Nothing "strange": when your variable is defined as a constructor parameter, it is already defined by the time constructor is accessing it, as opposed to ... not. As to you question, just make it `lazy` in `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a use case for early initializers

```
case class B(vs: String*) extends {
  override val variable: Seq[String] = vs
} with A {
  //override def hi(): Unit = ???
}
```

[In Scala, what is an "early initializer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer)

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/early-initializers.html