# Make a lazy field be evaluated

Tags: scala

Here is  Scala code:

```
  class FullDescription(val description: String) 
  class Logger {
      val description = //?????

      def onAttach(description: String) = 
       description = new FullDescription(description)

      // val lazy description = onAttach(???) -- 

      // ops! we don't know its actual argument, 
      // besides we should be able to make 
      // val description be evaluated from onAttach(...) and not vise versa
    }
```

It's given that for any class `Logger` it's guaranteed the method `onAttach` will be called only once. But it's unknown when the method `onAttach` will be called.

Is it possible to remain `val description` **immutable** and how do I do that? A `lazy` evaluation or something else?

Comment: I don't think it would be any different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161401/initializing-a-val-lately situation

Comment: It's never guaranteed that your method will only be called once as far as the compiler is concerned, neither is it guaranteed that you won't try to access `description` before calling `onAttach`.

Comment: You can pretty well ensure 0 or one invocations of a method if it's `private` and used in exactly one place in the source code to initialize a `lazy val`.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I didn't get it.